"Il y a" vs "Il y avait" for "ago"?
Another excerpt from L'Étranger:

Oui, c'était l'heure où, il y avait bien longtemps, je me sentais content.

I would have expected that to read il y a bien longtemps. What is the nuance of meaning by moving il y a into the past tense? And is this to say you could also have Il y a eu longtemps or il y aura longtemps or il y aurais longtemps? What would these things mean?

They are not both ago. That's the issue with trying to take it into French. A long time ago, il y a longtemps que etc. versus: Il y avait longtemps que=It had been a long time that.

@Lambie Ok for Il y avait longtemps que je ne t'avais pas vu → "I hadn't seen you for a long time/it had been a long time that.../since...". But that is not what il y avait bien longtemps in relation to c'était l'heure means in Camus's sentence.

Yes, it was the hour, a long time past, when I had felt happy

There is a slight nuance between il y a longtemps [...] and il y avait longtemps [...].
The time reference of the first form (il y a) is the time when the narrator reports what happened (I used to feel happy a long time ago [from now]) while the time reference of the second one (il y avait) is the time of the event itself (I used to feel happy "a long time ago from then"), i.e. it was already long over at that time.
About the variants you suggest, I agree with Frank's answer.

I can't tell a big nuance in the meaning in this case. It sounds to me like the two work here. I agree with the nuances explained by jlliagre, but in the end, the author se sentait content somewhere in the past compared to the time of the narration, and the imparfait il y avait does not seem to introduce something in the past of another reference point, as can happen in other examples.
Il y eut longtemps or il y a eu longtemps seem unlikely to me. Il y aura longtemps is possible, but we need a sentence to look at. Same for il y aurait longtemps. For example: il y aura longtemps que tu seras arrivé, et nous serons déjà à table, il y aurait longtemps que tu serais arrivé, et nous aurions déjà discuté cette affaire, ... The narrative effect is to explore future possibilities.

Il y a and il y avait are not the same tenses. The entire sentence is in the imparfait.
